# I want to ask for user input again if the entered number doesnot consists in the matrix given?

Tags: python

```
def create_seating_price_chart(row_number, col_number):
    """
    seating price chart
    :param row_number:
    :param col_number:
    :return:
    """
    seats = []
    for row in range(row_number):
        seat_price = []
        for col in range(col_number):
            seat_price.append(random.randint(500, 1000))
        seats.append(seat_price)
    return seats


def display_seating_price_chart():
    """
    display seating price
    """
    print("----------Display Seating Price Chart----------")
    print('There are ' + str(len(chart_2d)) + ' row and ' + str(len(chart_2d[0])) + ' column in the plane\n')
    for row in chart_2d:
        print(row)
    print("----------------------------------------------\n")


def find_max_value(pricechart_2d):
    """
    Find Max Value
    :return:
    """
    max_price = chart_2d[0][0]
    for row in chart_2d:
        for price in row:
            if price > max_price: max_price = price
    return max_price


def find_min_value(pricechart_2d):
    """
    Find Min Value
    :return:
    """
    min_price = chart_2d[0][0]
    for row in chart_2d:
        for price in row:
            if price < min_price: min_price = price
    return min_price


def calculate_average_price(chart_2d):
    """
    average price"""
    rows, cols = len(chart_2d), len(chart_2d[0])
    total = 0
    for row in chart_2d:
        total += sum(row)
        return total / (rows * cols)


def find_seats_with_price(chart_2d, price):
    """
    find seats"""
    seats = []
    for i in range(len(chart_2d)):
        for j in range(len(chart_2d[i])):
            if chart_2d[i][j] == price:
                seats.append([i, j])
    return seats


def display_seat_list(pricechart_2d):
    """
    display seat"""
    highest_price = find_max_value(chart_2d)
    lowest_price = find_min_value(chart_2d)
    seats = find_seats_with_price(chart_2d, lowest_price)
    print("--Display seat list with lowest price--")
    for seat in seats: print(seat)
    print('---------------------------------------------')

    seats = find_seats_with_price(chart_2d, highest_price)
    print('---Display seat list with highest price--')
    for seat in seats: print(seat)
    print('---------------------------------------------')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    display_title()

    chart_2d = create_seating_price_chart(ROW_NUMBER, COLUMN_NUMBER)
    display_seating_price_chart()

    highest_price = find_max_value(chart_2d)
    print('The highest price is ' + '$' + str(highest_price))

    lowest_price = find_min_value(chart_2d)
    print('The lowest price is ' + '$' + str(lowest_price))

    average_price = calculate_average_price(chart_2d)
    print('The average price is $ ' + str(average_price))

    display_seat_list(chart_2d)

    while True:
        try:
            
            price = int(input('Enter price you are looking for: '))
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter an valid integar")
            continue
        else:
            break     
    seats = find_seats_with_price(chart_2d, price)
    print('Here are the seats you may wish to book-')
    for seat in seats: print(seat)
    print('-----------------------------------------\n')
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Simply check and only if the check works out leave the `while True:` loop:

```
while True:
    try:
        price = int(input('Enter price you are looking for: '))
        if price in (20,50,900):  # use your list of valid values here
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid price")
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter an valid integar")
```